# Override exception message of SendFailedException getInvalidAddresses()

Tags: spring-boot, exception, error-handling, overriding, jakarta-mail

I use javax.mail dependency spring-boot-starter-mail and i want to override the error message that user get when they provide wrong email or email with domain that dose not exist. How can i override the error message of javax.mail.SendFailedException from the method getInvalidAddresses?
I want to override and pass the user a nice error message. I have my own GlobalExceptionClass which i use for all diffrent Exceptions inside my app:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

     @ExceptionHandler({SendFailedException.class})
     private ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> handleSendFailException(SendFailedException sfe){
     
       if (sfe.getInvalidAddresses() != null) {
          System.out.println("INVALID ADRESSS");
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new 
        MessageResponse("adress is inavlid"));
       }
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new 
       MessageResponse("invalidadress"));
       }
     }
```

My Controller Class

```
    @PostMapping("/offers")
public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> mailOffer(@Valid @RequestBody OffersDto offersDto) throws 
    MessagingException {
    String succMessage = "success.";
    offersService.addOffer(offersDto);
    offersService.sendMail(offersDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse(succMessage));
}
```

Services class

```
    public Offers sendMail(OffersDto offersDto) throws MessagingException  {
     ///messaging methods, attributes
    }
```

i just replicated this exception handling the same as for other methods, but above code dose not overrides the exception message

Answer (score 0):

You have to try/catch checked exception and in catch or finally block throw new unchecked custom exception, after that handle your Custom exception(you must add attributes of MessagingException to your custom exception for checking statements)

```
@ExceptionHandler({CustomException.class})
```

Comment: i dont understand your answer do you have an example? what doyou mean with the last part?
after that handle your Custom exception(you must add attributes of MessagingException to your custom exception for checking statements)